# Why only the second Frame shows in a StackLayout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Stacklayout that contains another Stacklayout and an Image. In order to have rounded corners for both children of the top Stacklayout, I added Frame for each child. Now, only the second child (Image) appear no matter how I change the visibility of the two children.

```
<StackLayout HeightRequest="135" WidthRequest="100" Margin="5,5" Grid.Row="0" Spacing="0"  HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start">
                
  <Frame IsVisible="false" CornerRadius="5" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" HasShadow="False" x:Name="InitialsFrame">
   <StackLayout IsVisible="false" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}">          
     <Label FontSize="60" Text="{Binding Initials}" TextColor="White" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" MaxLines="1" x:Name="InitialsLabel">                          
     </Label>                    
   </StackLayout>
  </Frame>
                             
  <Frame IsVisible="true" CornerRadius="5" IsClippedToBounds="True" Padding="0" x:Name="ImageFrame">
   <Image IsVisible="true" Source="{Binding Image}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" x:Name="IconImage" />
  </Frame>
</StackLayout>
```

Without the two Frames, I could choose which child to appear by setting IsVisible to True. But now, setting IsVisible does not work any more. Is there another way to conditionally choose which child to appear?

Comment: IsVisible of the first frame is set to false, so it's children will never be visible

Comment: I also set IsVisible in C# code. The IsVisible in xaml is only a placeholder. I can try removing IsVisible in xaml to see if this makes any difference.

Comment: please post the code that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @Jason  I found that removing IsVisible in xaml did solve the problem. My C# code is something like this: if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(group.IconBlobName)) { ImageFrame.IsVisible = false; InitialsFrame.IsVisible = true;} else {ImageFrame.IsVisible = true; InitialsFrame.IsVisible = false;}
Thank you for the help!

Comment: To explain why removing IsVisible in XAML helped: When an item is not visible, it is excluded from the layout. Starting with `IsVisible="false"` in XAML, means the initial layout excluded the item. Normally this is not a problem: when you later change IsVisible, the page should be re-laid-out. HOWEVER, that only works automatically *when you change it by changing a Binding*. If you change it in *code*, under some circumstances you have to explicitly force layout to be called. Since you found a solution, I'll leave it at that.

Comment: ... If you start with both items visible (the default), then later set one of them to `false`, the display gets redrawn. (Redraw is not the same as re-layout.) The hidden item will be invisible. Sometimes, the result is that "empty space" is left where the first item was. Similar to the original problem, the fix is to explicitly force layout. (Going back to the original problem, layout height was zero, because started invisible. "redrawing" with visible *did* draw it - but with zero height - so nothing was actually shown.) At least this is my theory, based on these problems.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thank you for the extra information.  It is very helpful to know.